# CRM 2013 Account Ribbon not showing accurately

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

We have recently upgraded from CRM 2011(On-premise) to CRM 2013(On-premise). After upgrade we have some JavaScript issues which we have fixed except the following one:

Whenever I open any account in CRM 2013, ribbon bar breaks-out, after enabling Debugger in IE-11, I found it was throwing some error:
Following is the screenshot of how ribbon is and the error:

[image: Ribbon_Error_Image]

After clicking yes on the above dialog below are the details what developer tools is showing:

[image]

After I close the record and reopen it, 
The following error shows up and ribbon works fine.
[image]

**PS:** This error show up, when I open the `Account Record` for the first time. After that it works fine, until the browser is closed.
The above error 'keydown' keeps coming again and again.

Comment: The fastest way to a solution would be to clear all customizations from the form (both events *and ribbon* ones) and then put them back a little piece at a time. This is 99.9% due to some unsupported code which used to work but now breaks.

Comment: Have a look at stack trace of javascript - if this is custom code problem, it should point you to invalid code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some unsupported customization's in JavaScript, that were working fine in CRM 2011.

As we had recently upgraded to CRM 2013.  So the unsupported JS was breaking the Ribbon UI. After disabling all the form JavaScript there were no errors.

I have updated the code and removed the unsupported JS. Now it's working fine.

The unsupported JS was taken from here:
http://innocentboysf09.blogspot.de/2014/05/crm-2011-like-subgrid-with-sorting-in.html

http://crmgreenbible.blogspot.de/2011/07/crm-2011-change-subgrid-fetchxml.html